# What are the non-gaming benefits of a dedicated GPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu

I am getting ready to purchase a new computer.  I don't do any gaming really at all.  I mostly will be compiling code, editing video and pics, compiling apps, etc.  I do like good graphics performance for watching movies, etc.  I am torn between two computers right now -both from System 76.  The Bonobo Extreme and the Kudu Professional. The Bonobo comes with the GTX870M from nVidia and the Kudu comes with the HD4600 from Intel.  If the cpu's were comparable, would I likely see any difference in performance between these two boxes?

Comment: You could use [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) with dedicated Nvidia/AMD GPUs, but I am not sure it matters much for compiling stuff.

Comment: Video editing can be quiet GPU intensive. If you are talking about some short youtube videos, it's probably okay, but the more professional you do it (higher resolutions, longer videos, you cut seldom or more often, ...) the more likely it is to get a stronger GPU. Although I can't compare those two CPUs objectively. The best would be if you could try the HD4600 somewhere to see if it suits your needs. Or at least a youtube video where someone shows the video editing performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One main thing is that your GPU won't use your RAM as a integrated GPU would! Yay!
A dedicated GPU is also noticeably faster, if you plan for rendering, animation , blah blah blah.
Also, You can take use of programming languages like CUDA, OpenCL and so on much more efficiently.
There are obviously much more, but some have already been given here.

About [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)

About [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)

Comment: Would the dedicated GPU help with running multiple VM's?

Comment: One thing again, it won't eat your RAM for its video memory. Sure, if you plan on running VM's with graphical needs, a dedicated Gpu will always help.

Comment: Not sure about yours or someone else's RAM (really hope you are human?), but that [Kudu thing](https://system76.com/laptops/kudu) can be upgraded to 16GB of DDR3 for it to "eat your RAM for its video memory".

Comment: @mikewhatever Intel HD graphics is a integrated GPU. It **has to** eat RAM for the video memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are many non-gaming benefits, such as video editing, movie watching, and other more graphical uses.

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: Would it make sense to spend the extra money upgrading the CPU and staying with the lower GPU?

Comment: Not if you don't do a ton of gaming or the things listed in my answer!

Comment: Would the dedicated GPU help with running multiple VM's?

Comment: Sure, it may help a little bit, but for what its worth, I would not suggest spending more money for it!

Comment: It would not really be so much a matter of "more" money as it would be where I spend the money.  If I get the Bonobo, I would leave the CPU alone and buy the box stock for $1589. That would be a 4710MQ (2.5ghz) CPU.  If I get the Kudu, I would upgrade the CPU to a 4810MQ (2.8ghz) and upgrade the HDD to mSata.That would be $1528.  The advantage of the Bonobo, besides the GPU, would be the ability to add LOTS more storage later.

Comment: Yes, so to answer your question, it would help having the gpu, but it is not mandatory!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! Please upvote if you found this helpful at all! Thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate all your help and especially the quick responses. One of the things I love about the open source community is the collaboration. One more question.  Imagine you were going to spend $1600 on a new box with the non-negotiables as follows:
Backlit keyboard
Numpad
Full Linux compatibility
Fast processing (CPU and GPU) for video editing, pic editing, complining code and apps, etc

Which of these would you buy?